# cannot assign or copy iostream object?

Tags: c++, iostream, initializer-list

`iostream` and other stream class are **not** actually class, but `typedef`s, right?

Here is the problem, I tried to initialize a `istream` object in initialization list, but unfortunately I got an error, code goes bellow:

```
class A 
{
    public:
        A(istream &is=cin): ais(is)
        {}

    private:
        istream ais;
};
```

Can't compile with g++, error:

```
synthesized method ‘std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here
```

I searched SO, found that, `iostream cannot be assigned or copy`. But why cannot I initialize it in the **initialization list**?

Cuz I think, the initialization list will invoke the object's constructor/copy-constructor, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code attempts to turn one `istream`, the one passed to the constructor, into two `istream`s, the one that was passed to the constructor and `ais`. An `istream` object represents that actual stream itself. There is only one stream and there is no way to somehow turn it into two streams.

It's not even clear what that would mean. If there's some data on the stream, does whichever stream reads first get it? Or do they both get it? If so, who or what duplicates it?

An `istream` is like a file *itself*. You cannot turn one file into two files without copying the data from one to the other yourself. You can, however, have as many references or pointers to the same `istream` as you want. The solution to your problem is probably to make `ais` a reference.

Answer (score 5):

You have the member variable declared as:

```
istream ais;
```

meaning the copy constructor will be invoked in the initializer list. This is not specific to the initializer list: you can't do this anywhere.

You could change the member variable to be a reference:

```
istream& ais;
```

but that means you have to ensure that the `istream` to which `ais` refers is valid for the lifetime of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

> iostream and other stream class are not actually class, but typedefs, right?

Yes, but that's not relevant.

> But why cannot I initialize it in the initialization list?

Because it can be neither copied nor assigned. Ctor init list is not magical. To create `ais` from `is` you need to make a copy, and you can't.

Answer (score 2):

The stream object represent a handle to streams of data. Copying that doesn't make sense. Also, this wouldn't be the right thing to copy only tge base part of a stream: this would be slicing off the interesting bit (although you could get hold of thr actually interesting portion by using the stream buffer).

What you want to initialize in your class if it holds a stream is a reference to the stream:

```
std::istream& ais;
```

Of course, this means that some external needs to keep the stream alive as long as you are using it. If this isn't what you want or need you can have your class hold e.g. an `std::ifstream` and take a `std::string` as constructor argument: if the string is non-empty you'd open the corresponding file. Otherwise you'd set your stream's `rdbuf()` to the one from `std::cin`:

```
if (name.empty())
    ais.open(name.c_str());
else
    ais.rdbuf(std::cin.rdbuf());
```

Comment: Actually, if it represented a handle, copying it would make perfect sense. There's no reason you can't have two handles to the same stream of data. The problem is that it represents the stream *itself*. And there is only one stream of data.

Comment: I think I said so. Interestingly, the `std::istream` actually **is** mostly a handle for a `std::streambuf`. However, the derived type actually own and embed the concrete stream buffer.

Comment: I think it's more accurately a 'container' than a 'handle'. The term 'handle' carries a lot of baggage that makes it seem analogous to file or socket handles.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers you already got, you can also initialize `ais` (as of your definition) with the *streambuf* of the stream you passed in (of course, the same caveat as with the reference applies: You must ensure that the streambuf stays valid until the object is destructed).

Initializing with the underlying streambuf is probably the closest to copying a stream you can do: While both still read from the same file and use the same buffering (and other processing the streambuf may do), all the formatting and error handling flags are separate.

To initialize `ais` with the streambuf, you write:

```
class A 
{
public:
  A(std::istream& is = std::cin):
    ais(is.rdbuf())
  {
  }
private:
  std::istream ais;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A 
{
    public:
        A(istream &is=cin): ais(is)
        {}

    private:
        istream& ais;
};
```

Notice the member is a reference type. As you've written it, you're making a copy to initialize the member.